# Can I have two domains for one website (Firebase)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have developed a Flutter website and use Firebase for my storage and hosting. Now I want to use two domains "www.mywebsite.de" and "www.mywebsite.fr". Can I do this with Firebase?

Comment: Just add both domains for Firebase hosting https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure multiple [custom domains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) for a single Firebase Hosting project. In fact this is quite common.

Just keep in mind that all domains will be serving the exact same content, unless you also [set up multiple sites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites) on the Firebase project.

So given your use-case, you may either serve the same resources to French and German users, or you can configure a separate site for each in the same project, and then serve different resources to French and German users.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful!